# as3 flash, browser, tabs and focus

Tags: flash, browser, focus

When I have several tabs open in my browser, I can 
cycle through them using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>, however if at any time I bring
a flash app to focus then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> no longer works... I manually have
to click somwhere outside the flash area and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>...

Is there a way for either

(a) the html that contains the flash to catch the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> and
steal it from flash

(b) the flash captures the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> releases it's focus to the browser
(and notifies it or passes through the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> event )..

I'm sure this has been asked before, and I'm sure if there is no way
to do this, it must bug the hell out of developers..

Any ideas, hacks, suggestions ?

Comment: not only ctrl-tab, all keyboard events are 'stollen'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but I'm to understand that the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> thing is a built-in hotkey for cycling through members of an array (like internet window tabs, buttons, or even language settings). If that is indeed the case, the I would think the only way to do what I believe you are suggesting is to put a bit of code in the actual Flash movie/file that says to ignore the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> key combination.

```
function f_keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    // Keyboard.TAB == 9
    if (Event.keyCode == Keyboard.TAB) {
        trace('Pressed the TAB key!');
        if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
            //the CTRL key on Windows; the COMMAND key on Macs;
            trace('Pressed the CTRL key!');
            //something i don't know XD
        }
    }
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, f_keyDown);
```

You might have to mess with the *FocusManager* class... I am unsure how you would go about it. Hope I helped a little...